# Adding blank attributes to content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, zurb-foundation, helper

I'm trying to make an element with a foundation tooltip which requires a `data-tooltip` attribute in the icon element (e.g., `<i class="..." data-tooltip, aria-haspopup=true>`).

I've managed to get the last attribute (`aria-haspopup`), but I cannot figure out how to set a blank attribute for `data-tooltip`.

Most recent attempt was to pass a nil value, but it prints out `"null"`:

```
    h.content_tag(:i, '', { class: source_type_icon, data: { tooltip: nil } , "aria-haspopup" => true } )
```

I also tried passing an array with a `:tooltip` symbol to `data:`, but, that did not work either. I can't figure out how to add a solo attribute with no values.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot have blank value for attribute. So I just use "" for it the last I did something similar. If you look at Rails code for such function:

```
    # File actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb
    def tag_option(key, value, escape)
      value = value.join(" ") if value.is_a?(Array)
      value = ERB::Util.h(value) if escape
      %(#{key}="#{value}")
    end
```

It always takes a value.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, just instead of `data: { tooltip: nil }` put `data: { tooltip: '' }`